# In my React Native app, the catch block always executes even though the request is successful

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, redux

In my React Native app, I am simply logging in a user or creating an account, but the catch block for my login and signup functions always executes even though the user successfully logs in or is successfully added to the database. So that means the success block (then) and the catch block both execute back to back.

In addition to the catch block bug, I see some yellow box warnings saying my JS is too slow in relation to the TextInput component. I don't know if those are related to the catch block issue though.

This bug has been affecting other people as well, but I haven't heard of anyone finding a solution yet. I've tested my login and signup routes in postman and they work as expected, no issues.

Here are the login and signup action creators:

Login:

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
   const props = { email, password };
   return (dispatch) => {
     // notifies REDUX store that an ajax request is in progress
     dispatch({ type: types.LOGIN_USER_START });

     axios.post('http://localhost:3000/signin', props)
       .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
       .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
   };
 };
```

Signup:

```
export const signupUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  const props = { email, password };
  return (dispatch) => {
    // notifies REDUX store that an ajax request is in progress
    dispatch({ type: types.SIGNUP_USER_START });

    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/signup', props)
      .then(user => signupUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => {
        signupUserFailed(dispatch);
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Hey, Can you post the complete error log.

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs somewhere in `loginUserSuccess`. Instead of `catch(()=>` you should use `catch((err)=>` and do something with the error, such as `console.log(err.stack)`, and then you'll know exactly

- What is wrong
- Where the problem is